# CakePHP sanitize utils

Tags: php, cakephp, controller

I can't get it works in my controller. The code is:

```
 App::import('Sanitize');
 class MyController extends AppController
 {
       public $uses = array('Sanitize');
       function Foo()
       {
             // Fatal error: Class 'Sanitize' not found
             $test = Sanitize::paranoid($data);
             // Fatal error: Call to a member function paranoid() on a non-object
             $test = $this->sanitize->paranoid($data);
       }
 }
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Which CakePHP version do you use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Importing core files has changed in CakePHP 2.x, which means you have to change `App::import('Sanitize');` to `App::uses('Sanitize', 'Utility');`. Also remove the `$uses` statement, it's for loading models and `Sanitize` is not a model.

With those modifications, your snippet will look like:

```
App::uses('Sanitize', 'Utility');
class MyController extends AppController
{
   function Foo()
   {
         $test = Sanitize::paranoid($data);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works. It's so strange that I didn't find this in docs.